# Смена иконки foreground сервиса android при переходе в разные состояния

Tags: java, android, kotlin

возник следующий вопрос. В моем приложении есть foreground сервис и привязанная к нему activity. Предположим, что у сервиса может быть несколько состояний, через которые он переходит при нажатии на кнопки в activity. Вопрос заключается в следующем: как мне менять иконку сервиса при его переходе из одного состояния в другое?

Comment: Нужно обновить уведомление. Это делается его заменой, через отображение нового уведомления с тем же ID.

Comment: Был вариант создать в сервисе функцию на проверку состояний, а потом при помощи when в .setSmallIcon при изменении состояний устанавливать соответствующую иконку. Но тут вопрос: как передать через кнопку в activity одно из состояний прямо в функцию

Comment: Способов передачи данных из активити в сервис много. Лично я бы делал через инжект RxRelay в оба компонента через DI. Если вы не использовали DI и RxJava, то попробуйте LocalBroadcastManager.

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        when(intent?.action) {
            ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE -> startForegroundService()
            ACTION_STOP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE -> stopForegroundService()
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    private fun startForegroundService() {
        startForeground(startId, getMyActivityNotification(smallIcon = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground))
    }

    private fun getMyActivityNotification(smallIcon: Int): Notification {
        val intent = Intent()
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, intent, 0)
        val b = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelID )
        b.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        b.setContentTitle("Title")
        b.setContentText("Simple text")
        b.setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
        START_NOT_STICKY
        return b.build()
    }

    private fun updateNotification() {
        val smallIcon: Int = when (mConnectionState) {
            ConnectionState.CONNECTED -> R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_black_24dp
            ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED -> R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_black_24dp}
        when (mServiceState) {
            ServiceState.BUSY -> R.drawable.ic_watch_later_black_24dp
            ServiceState.IDLE -> R.drawable.ic_pan_tool_black_24dp
        }
        val notification: Notification = getMyActivityNotification(smallIcon)
        val mNotificationManager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        mNotificationManager.notify(startId, notification)
    }
```